# Changing order of characters in a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, api

I'm catching the date from a form as a string and pass it to a API-Request-URL.

The date string is in this format:  **16**02**2019**
But the API accepts a date string only in this format: **2019**02**16**.

Basically, in my string, I need to change the position of the first 2 characters with the position of the last 4 characters.

I fixed the issue as follow:

```js
let date = e.target.elements.date.value; // 16022019

const dateFirst = date.slice(0, 2);
const dateMiddle = date.slice(2, 4);
const dateLast = date.slice(4, 8);
date = `${dateLast}${dateMiddle}${dateFirst}`; // 20190216
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good solution. Is there any better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you didn't mess the indexes I see nothing wrong. But it could be a one-liner (I don't see the need of intermediate variables).

Comment: Using slice is probably fast, easy to maintain and therefore the solution to go with. Other solutions might be more elegant, but ... who needs them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your method. in case you want to know alternate you can try this.

This uses regex to capture digits of desired width and than places to desired place.

```js
let str = `16022019`
console.log(str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/,"$3$2$1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** and **[rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)** syntax to do it.

```js
const str = `16022019`;
[d, d1, m, m1, ...year] = str.split("");
const dateStr = [...year,m,m1,d,d1].join("");
console.log(dateStr);
```

Comment: Do avoid the double join, just do -> `[...year,m,m1,d,d1].join("");`

Answer (score 1):

How about mapping the positions:

```
[/*y*/ 4, 6, /*m*/ 2, /*d*/ 0].reduce((acc, p) => acc + date.slice(p, p + 2), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

using substring

```js
var a = '16022019';
console.log(a.substring(a.length - 4, a.length) + a.substring(2, 4) + a.substring(0, 2))
```

using substr

```js
var a = '16022019';
console.log(a.substr(a.length-4,4)+a.substr(2,2)+a.substr(0,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way working with dates:

```js
function yyyymmdd() {
  var x = new Date();
  var y = x.getFullYear().toString();
  var m = (x.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var d = x.getDate().toString();
  (d.length == 1) && (d = '0' + d);
  (m.length == 1) && (m = '0' + m);
  var yyyymmdd = y + m + d;
  return yyyymmdd;
}

console.log(yyyymmdd("16022019")) // outputs 20190216
```

References: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/184459

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this by using Array#reverse and Array#join.

```js
const data = "16022019"

const res = data.split(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/).reverse().join("");

console.log(res);
```